# Is there a library for Python that gives the script name for a given unicode character or string?

Tags: python, unicode

Is there a library that tells what script a particular unicode character belongs to?

For example for the input "u'ሕ'" it should return Ethiopic or similar.

Comment: The good news is that yes, there is indeed a library that tells what script a particular Unicode code point belongs to.  The bad news is that that library is part of the Perl distribution, not part of Python.  How you get from one to the other I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the `Scripts.txt` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-

import bisect

script_file = "/path/to/Scripts.txt"
scripts = []

with open(script_file, "rt") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        line = line.split("#", 1)[0].strip()
        if line:
            rng, script = line.split(";", 1)
            elems = rng.split("..", 1)
            start = int(elems[0], 16)
            if len(elems) == 2:
                stop = int(elems[1], 16)
            else:
                stop = start
            scripts.append((start, stop, script.lstrip()))

scripts.sort()
indices = [elem[0] for elem in scripts]

def find_script(char):
    if not isinstance(char, int):
        char = ord(char)
    index = bisect.bisect(indices, char) - 1
    start, stop, script = scripts[index]
    if start <= char <= stop:
        return script
    else:
        return "Unknown"

print find_script(u'A')
print find_script(u'Д')
print find_script(u'ሕ')
print find_script(0x1000)
print find_script(0xE007F)
print find_script(0xE0080)
```

Note that is code is neither robust nor optimized. You should test whether the argument denotes a valid character or code point, and you should coalesce adjacent equivalent ranges.

Comment: It took me a few seconds to figure out what you meant by the Scripts.txt file, but this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Please post clarification about what is ``Scripts.txt`` as this is not obvious and will help any people that will have this problem in the future

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the data in the [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) module is what you are looking for:

```
print unicodedata.name(u"ሕ")
```

prints

```
ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE HHE
```

The printed name can be used to look up the corresponding character:

```
unicodedata.lookup("ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE HHE")
```

Comment: That doesn’t work: you need to access the **Script** property. The name is not the same as the script, and you must never attempt to infer the one from the other. This is a trivial operation in Perl using the standard Unicode::UCD module’s charscript() function: `perl -MUnicode::UCD=charscript -le 'print charscript(0x1215)'` prints `Ethiopic`, code point 0x3B1 is `Greek`, code point 0x1000 is `Myanmar`, etc.  Is there an easy say to call Perl library  code from Python?  Seems like what you need here.

Comment: @tchrist: I know it's not the *script* property.  The question is somewhat vague, stating it should return "Ethiopic or similar".  Thanks for pointing this out explicitly -- I probably should have mentioned it in the asnwer.